# Boost.Icl how to define infinite endpoint for types without infinity?

Tags: c++, boost, intervals

Boost.Icl has four interval types: 
closed [a,b] for a<=x<=b,
open (a,b) for a<x<b,
left-open (a,b] for a<x<=b,
rigth-open [a,b) for a<=x<b.

That's enough for types which have explicit minimal and maximal values: `double`, all integers, `boost::time_interval`, `boost::ptime`, ...
But there are types like `string` and `vector`, which have the minimal value (i.e. empty string) but not the maximal one. It makes impossible to define an interval with infinite right endpoint.
Intervals (and intervals with infinite right end) have sense for strings and vectors,  for sharding.

Simplest solution looks like to use `tuple<bool, string>` in place of `string` (true means infinity so such a pair will be bigger than any string). But it will force me to use the pair instead of string everywhere in the program (or to create pairs before any interval operation, which implies string copying).

Is there a better solution?
Maybe to add a 5th and 6th interval types into Icl: closed_to_infinity [a,+inf) and open_to_infinity (a,+inf) ?